# C++ reading in specific segments of data from a file redirected to my program

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

I'm working on a program that takes a redirected file as input. For example, if my program was called foo I would call the program with `./foo < input.txt`. The files I'm running through my program are supposed to be formatted with a single integer on the first line, two integers on the second line. So something like

```
3
1 8
```

I'm finding that some of the files have extraneous characters though on the first line that I need to ignore. Something like

```
3 t
1 8
```

I was reading in the data by just doing `cin >> var >> var 2 >> var3;` but when that extra t gets thrown into the mix it screws everything up. What would be the best way of working around this problem? Is there some way to after I cin the first variable tell it to skip the rest of the line? Or would I use the `getline` function and then somehow parse that? Thanks.

Comment: pls post your code for better diagnosis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is of the form

```
[number] garbage
[number] [number] garbage
```

and you know that the numbers are always in the correct position on the line, then I'd use `std::getline()` to read each line then attempt to read the expected number of integers from each line that you read.

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking. Any recommendation on how to parse each line?

Comment: @blcArmadillo:  Yes; use an `istringstream`, read the two integers, check for errors, and ignore the rest of the contents of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the obvious way would be to use `std::getline` to read a line of text, use the `std::string` you get from that to initialize an `std::istringstream`, read the correct number of items from that line, and repeat as needed.